# Looking for appropriate time series econometrics materials, with Stata examples

Tags: time-series, self-study, references, stata

I want to know whether my data are trending, co-integrated, have unit roots, have autocorrelation, or have heteroskedasticity.  I want to do all this using Stata, so please suggest material or direct me a book on these topics

Answer (score 2):

You want to start with an introductory econometrics book. Stock and Watson's [Introduction to Econometrics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0138009007) covers these topics with stata replication files.

Here is a link to the replication files

http://wps.aw.com/aw_stock_ie_3/178/45691/11696965.cw/index.html